# max existence interval of the solution of the Cauchy problem for $\alpha<\frac{1}{e}$

Tags: real-analysis

\begin{cases} 
y'(t) = 1+log(y(x)) \\
y(0) = \alpha
\end{cases}

I want prove the solution $\phi(x)$ touches the x-axis if $0<\alpha<\frac{1}{e}$.
I know the solution is decreasing and concave but this isn't enough to prove it.
Can I use the comparison theorem?

$\int_{\alpha}^{y} \frac{ds}{1+logs}=\int_{0}^{x}du=x>0$

$ \int_{\alpha}^{y} \frac{ds}{1+logs}$ is positive so , because $\frac{1}{1+logs}<0$, $y(x)\rightarrow0$?

Comment: Why don't you think "decreasing and concave" is enough?

Comment: because my teacher wants a proof  studying the integral up